# <table> side by side but second one is scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have something like

```
<div container style="width: 100%">
    <table id="t1" style="width: 40%">
            ...
    </table>
        <table id="t2" style="width: 60%">
            ...
    </table>
</div>
```

both tables has `display: inline-block`
but the catch is, `t2` is tooo long of a table (several `td`s) and I want `t2` to be scrollable.

**EDIT**: I'm so sorry but "scrollable" = horizontally :) (I think the hint was the 'several tds')

Comment: Why don't you place your table in a div? and than <div style="width: 60% ;overflow:auto;">

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to you or not, but have you seen responsive tables? http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables - Go to their example page and shrink your browsers width. It sounds like you are asking for something like this.

Comment: Saint is right, place it in a div and make the div scrollable. Many examples online on how to do that.

Comment: @adam I actually needed that for a project, thanks +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs cleanup, but is this the effect you're going for?

```
<div container style="width: 100%">
    <div style="width: 40%; float:left;">    
        <table id="t1">
        ...
        </table>
    </div>    
    <div style="width: 60%; overflow-x:auto;">
        <table id="t2">
        ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YudJn/3/

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS for t2

```
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
```

Comment: Will not work until used with some display property like `display: block` and of course some fixed height.

Comment: you should swap x and y sir :D

Comment: Edited, you usually "scroll" on Y-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You could set `#t1` to `position:fixed` and rely on body scrolling to scroll the longer table. Keep in mind that doing that, you'd need to adjust your margin on `#t2` to accommodate the overlap. Or, you'd need to place `#t2` in a fixed-height div with `overflow:scroll`.